# Looking for a method in java to input (x,y) to an array on every iteration

Tags: java

I'm looking for adding a point (x,y) on every instance of an array call in java
This is what i'm trying to do 
       declare an array like

```
int [] weight = new int[100];
```

i'm looking to add values in the next step

```
 weight.add(3,4);
 weight.add(5,6);
```

The idea what i'm looking for is when i do an iteration something like this

```
for(int i =0;i< weight.length;i++)
     print "Weight"+i+ "has"+ weight[i]
```

it should print

```
       Weight 0 has (3,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a class for each point which contains an x, and y coord... using code something like...

```
class Point{
    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then instead of making an array of ints, make the array of Points...
something like...

```
//create array of points size 100
Point [] weight = new Point[100];

//add point to array
int i = 0; //set this to the index you want the point at
weight[i] = new Point(0, 0); //add whatever point you want to index i

//then you can loop through your array of points and print them out
for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++){

    System.out.println("Weight " + i + " has (" + weight[i].x + "," + weight[i].y + ");\n"
}
```

Abstracting your x and y coordinates into a Point class is a better design in my opinion. It will help you keep track of your data better in your mind when you program. Furthermore, you can add methods to your point class such as `double distance(Point other)` to return the distance between two points...

Comment: Technically speaking, `distance` should be a method which takes a single point...

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma you're right... I was in a rush... thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Create a private inner class `Point` as:

```
private static class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    //...........
}
```

Then, for each `x, y` pair create a point object and put it in `weight`.